# Moving image between folders in SIRV S3 NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I'm working on a project where i should make a copy of some images in an other folder in SIRV S3.

I'm using this code, and it working for most of my pictures:

```
    const options = {
                      method: 'GET',
                      url: photoUrl,
                      encoding: null,
                      headers: {
                        'Authorization': req.headers.token
                      }
                   }
    return request(options).then(data => {
        const params = {
            Bucket: sirvS3Bucket,
            Key: uploadPath + '/' +fileName,
            Body: data
        };
        return s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, data) {
            if (s3Err) {
                console.log('s3 error' + s3Err);
            }
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('\n[Pictures 96]: ' + error + '\n');
    });
```

but i'm getting issue for some pictures:

StatusCodeError: 400 - {"type":"Buffer","data":[60,104,116,109,108,62,10,32,32,60,104,101,97,100,62,10,32,32,32,32,60,109,101,116,97,32,99,104,97,114,115,101,116,61,39,117,116,102,45,56,39,62,32,10,32,32,32,32,60,116,105,116,108,101,62,69,114,114,111,114,58,32,70,97,105,108,101,100,32,116,111,32,100,101,99,111,100,101,32,112,97,114,97,109,32,38,35,51,57,59,47,99,117,114,114,121,47,53,97,56,49,100,53,48,100,48,53,55,51,56,100,51,100,48,48,48,49,49,56,102,56,47,118,101,108,111,117,116,37,69,57,37,50,48,99,104,111,117,120,37,50,48,102,108,101,117,114,37,50,48,110,111,105,115,101,116,116,101,95,79,75,46,106,112,103,45,49,53,56,49,56,54,48,56,50,51,52,53,50,46,106,112,103,38,35,51,57,59,60,47,116,105,116,108,101,62,10,32,32,32,32,60,115,116,121,108,101,62,42,32,123,10,32,32,109,97,114,103,105,110,58,32,48,59,10,32,32,112,97,100,100,105,110,103,58,32,48,59,10,32,32,111,117,116,108,105,110,101,58,32,48,59,10,125,10,10,98,111,100,121,32,123,10,32,32,112,97,100,100,105,110,103,58,32,56,48,112,120,32,49,48,48,112,120,59,10,32,32,102,111,110,116,58,32,49,51,112,120,32,34,72,101,108,118,101,116,105,99,97,32,78,101,117,101,34,44,32,34,76,117,99,105,100,97,32,71,114,97,110,100,101,...

Does anyone know why i'm getting this issue for only SOME pictures ?

Thanks

Comment: check the pictures `content-type` header... are they properly marked with the correct one? by default, if you upload through API and do not specify it, it will be  `octet-stream` if I'm not mistaken ...

Comment: Have you asked the Sirv developers for help? https://sirv.com/contact/

Comment: i tryied adding the content-type in the header, but it doesn't seem wokrin

Comment: @DanRoberts thanks, i'll ask them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I corrected this by using http.get instead of request